# Manufacturer tree structure

Tags: magento-1.9, category-tree, manufacturer

I am searching for a way to make a  brand tree. I want to have a

> Manufacturer -> Brand -> Product line

For every single level I need to store a `description` and `logo`. Task will be easy to implement with categories, if there was no logo. I have been searching for some extension, there is a lot of extension for `Shop by brand`, but they do not support a tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

["Just" add a new category attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11721025/1480397), then you can add the logo, description, etc. and use categories to do this.

You can even think about using something like [FireGento_DynamicCategories](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-dynamiccategory) to fill the categories based on product attributes, so you only need to maintain the attributes.